# Is it better to hookup lots of methods to an event or one method that loops through a list of methods?

Tags: c#, delegates, event-handling

By better I mean performance.

I have a bunch of objects with this in the constructor:

```
someObject.Event += (o,e) => {(if e.Value == someValue) this.OnEvent();};
```

And I was thinking of creating a class like this (depending on the answer to this question):

```
class PassthroughRegistry
{
    List<Action> _actions = new List<Action>();
    object _someValue;

    public PassthroughRegistry(object someValue)
    {
        _someValue = someValue
    }

    public void Register(Action action)
    {
        _actions.Add(action);
    }

    public void OnEvent(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.SomeValue == _someValue)
             foreach (var action in actions)
                  action.Invoke();
    }
}
```

and then in someObject just hooking up the one method.

```
class SomeObject
{
    PassthroughRegistry registry;
    SomeObject()
    {
        registry = new PassthroughRegistry("someValue");
        this.Event += registry.OnEvent;
    }
}
```

someObject is essentially a singleton shared by the other object instances.

So basically the question is - is it faster to hookup lots of individual delegates to an event handler, or to hookup one that calls a bunch of delegates?

Comment: They're basically doing the same thing, more or less.

Comment: I'm sure that comments will appear to tell the OP to just measure it. It is not possible to measure all cases. It is important to understand this issue on a more conceptual level in order to understand how to measure. The question is valid.

Comment: If you're hooking tons of events, then maybe this is an issue. Otherwise, why worry about performance when the event is short-circuited with an if? I'd focus on readability.

Comment: @MillieSmith How can you know that performance doesn't matter to the OP? He is asking specifically about it after all.

Comment: I believe this is the typical case of "what performs more" and it's based on pure speculation.

Comment: @usr I would tell OP not to measure it. I would just point OP to avoid re-inventing square wheels and wasting time on something like re-implementing events in C#.

Comment: @usr I didn't say "this is definitely not a problem for you". I simply said where I thought it would be relevant and irrelevant.

Comment: @usr Well, the vast majority of people who claim to be concerned about performance don't actually have a performance problem, and those that do often don't know what is actually causing their performance problems.  The fact that someone says they care about performance doesn't mean they actually have a performance problem.

Comment: Yeah, what Servy said. A lot of OPs will try to optimize things that don't need to be optimized, and that's what my first comment was trying to avoid. I've been bitten more than once by premature optimization - it's not fun.

Comment: It would be very non-intuitive and difficult to use `PassthroughRegistry` class if it was in some framework. That would mean more bugs and that matters much more than couple of microseconds saved, if any...